# How to force wrap icons like iPhone?

Tags: android

So this may be regarded a silly question but I prefer how my iPhone forces you to lay out the icons linearly with out any spaces for icons on what is essentially the home screen/launcher.  I spend most of my time I feel like simple filling in the blank spaces without any way to force it to wrap.

I'm confused what benefit there is in having blank spaces unless you can't reach parts of your phone from having hands that are to small.

Is there a way to achieve this ?